# jquery ui datepicker.. can i make it static?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calendar, datepicker

This is a simple question.

I want to create an inline calendar that does not have any selectable dates.  I want the date to be selected by a preset hidden input field.  Should I use the datepicker plugin.  This seems like the wrong thing to use since I am not really doing any picking persay..

anyone have any exp with this.  Just need to make a static calendar.

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/inlineDatePicker.html

something like this but without dates or months selectable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes You can use it to make static calendar (but best if You are already using some jquery ui features so no additional js will be necessary for download).

You can use two options:

1. inline (will show datepicker calendar in line)

> ```
> $('#datepicker').datepicker({inline: true});
> ```

1. disable (will disable calendar)

> $('#datepicker').datepicker({disabled: true});

Full code (working)

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var staticDate = $("#static_date").val();
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
inline: true,
disabled: true,
defaultDate: staticDate
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="hidden" id="static_date" value="01/01/2012" />
<div id="datepicker"></div>
</body>
```

You can see, that datepicker is bounded to div not textfield.
First line in body is place where You can define static date. Remember too use format that is also set in datepicker.

Comment: the disabling part isnt working.  i can still select dates on the calendar.  i also need to be able to set up a date manually on page load.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the extra downloadtime for jqueryui, I would advice against resorting to use jqueryui and have a disabled datepicker staticly display on a page. There is better php libraries to output calendars, or even just print it out yourself, if the calendar is not too complex.

Comment: i am already loading jquery ui for my entire project so the download time is not really a concern

Comment: Then my point is voided. darek has a answer with excellent detail on how to use jqueryui for a static calendar.